# Using Total on a list supplied by a rule

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I'm confused as to why `Total` complains about a nonatomic expression here:

```
Total[myList] /. {myList -> {1,2}}
Total::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[myList]. >>
3

Total[{1,2}]
3
```

If it's important, here's the context in which I'm using it:

```
obj = someClass[myList -> {}, anotherList -> {1,2}];
calculateStuff[someClass[props___]] := (1 + Total[myList] * Mean[anotherList]) /. {props};
calculateStuff[obj]
Total::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[myList]. >>
0
```

I can't find any discussion about using a rule to transform a symbol into a list like this. One of the examples in the `ReplaceAll` documentation makes it seem like this is okay. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, `myList` is an undefined symbol (which is atomic), you then apply `Total` on it. The latter expects a list and it complains about it and returns unevaluated. *Only then* is the replacement used, which results in `Total[{1,2}]` and the final result of three. You should have used `Total[myList /. {myList -> {1,2}}]` instead. This replaces `myList` *before* `Total` is executed.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That's what I would use if I were only doing a single Total, my actual function is more complicated so I updated my example to be a little more precise. It would be convenient to only have to do the replacement once, is there no way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to forbid the evaluation of `Total[myList]` and `Mean[anotherList]` until you have actually replaced the arguments with the specific lists:

```
obj = someClass[myList -> {}, anotherList -> {1, 2}];
calculateStuff[someClass[props___]] := 
  Unevaluated[1 + Total[myList]*Mean[anotherList]] /. {props};

calculateStuff[obj]
(* 1 *)
```